# Is XBMC/Kodi compatible with Xubuntu?

Tags: xbmc, kodi

I installed xbmc and for reasons not quite clear to me, the friggin application won't play. The KODI screen pops up for a few seconds, then disappears.
The xbmc or kodi icon doesn't appear in the list of multimedia apps.  I can only access it if I open up the  software center.  I hit the icon and all the files associated with the application appear but nothing else.  The xbmc application doesn't open. I've uninstalled and reinstalled everything via package manager but nothing seems to work.
I'm currently running xubuntu. Should I be using ubuntu instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Kodi should work just fine on Xubuntu or any Ubuntu flavor - I use it most often on Lubuntu myself. The desktop doesn't matter.

It sounds like maybe Kodi didn't quite install. You can check to verify whether it's installed by trying to launch it from the terminal. If you open up a terminal, you might be able to launch the program using the command `kodi`. Try that and see if the app will start.

I don't usually recommend adding software from third-party sources, but Team Kodi recommends installing from their PPA directly, which they maintain and update outside the normal Ubuntu software channels. If you can't get the one in the official repos to work on your device, you could try their method: http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux#Installing_Kodi_on_Ubuntu-based_distributions